# Render object as Blazor component, not ToString()

Tags: blazor

If I run the code below, the page shows just ToString() results, not the components. Is there a way to make `@child` rendered just as when I hardcoded `<Dog>` or `<Cat>`?

I do not know what parent class or interface a Razor component inherits, so I just used an `object` List.

Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@foreach(var child in children)
{
  @child;
}

@code{
  List<object> children = new();
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    children.Add(new Dog() { Message = "Doge" });
    children.Add(new Cat() { Message = "Meow" });
  }
}
```

Cat.razor

```
<h3>The cat says @Message</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Message{ get; set; }
}
```

Dog.razor

```
<h3>The dog says @Message</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Message{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: think you're looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't create instances of components and then hand them to the renderer to use.  The Renderer manages component lifecycles.

To do want you want in the question you need to use the `DynamicComponent` like this:

Cat (to make it distinct)

```cs
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <h3>The cat says @Message</h3>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Message { get; set; }
}
```

Dog (again distinct):

```cs
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <h3>The dog says @Message</h3>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Message { get; set; }
}
```

And Index to show how to use them:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@foreach(var component in this.Components)
{
    <DynamicComponent Type=component.ComponentType Parameters=component.Parameters />
}

@code {

    private List<Component> Components = new List<Component> {
        new Component { ComponentType = typeof(Dog), Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Message", "DogE" } } },
        new Component { ComponentType = typeof(Cat), Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Message", "Meow" } } },
    };

    private class Component
    {
        public Type? ComponentType { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object>? Parameters { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which will give you:

[image]

Comment: I do not know which .NET version you are using, but it seems that the property name is not `ComponentType` but just `Type` in .NET 7.0. Also, isn't it `new Component(){`, instead of  `new Component{`?

Comment: Net7.0 & C# 10.  `ComponentType` is just the global variable name (of type `Type`) in the `Component` class.  Calling it `Type` could be confusing.  In the later versions of C# there's more than one way to instantiate an object - check them out.